# Draw small rounded and colored boxes of same height in math environment

Tags: math-mode

How can I create same-height boxes (with rounded corners and background color) around triples of letters in math mode?

I tried $ T = \boxed{ban}\boxed{ana}\boxed{ban}\boxed{$$$} $ but it also results in differents heights.

As reference, please see following image I saw in slides by Sebastian Wild in slide 30 in https://www.wild-inter.net/teaching/comp526/notes-06-text-indexing.pdf . I would to all of these boxes to have the same height.

[image: Array with letters in irregular-heighted boxes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the use of the tcolorbox package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mytcbox}{
before={}, % code before the box
after={\ }, % code after the box
box align=base, % 
size=fbox,
boxrule=0.35mm, % rule thickness
arc=1.25mm, % rounding radius
colback=red!25, % background color
before upper={\strut}, % insert invisible rule before the box content to have uniform height
}
\begin{document}
\(T=\mytcbox{ban}\mytcbox{ana}\)\mytcbox{\$\$\$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try creating your own `\mybox` command as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mybox}{ m } % ❶
  {\boxed{\mathstrut#1}} % ❷
```

(If you get an error with the line marked ❶, you have an old LaTeX. You can either change this to `\newcommand{\mybox}[1]`, load the `xparse` package (better) or update your LaTeX (best).)

What `\mathstrut` does at ❷ is it creates an invisible item with the height and depth of a parenthesis which should give you uniform depth.

I'd also note that your output is printing its contents in text mode. Is that really what you want? If not, you can change the line at ❷ to

```
{\boxed{$\mathstrut#1$}}
```

Comment: I liked this solution. I did not know \mathstrut before. However I could not find how to turn this \boxed into colored and with rounded corners. Is it possible?

Comment: For the rounded corners and colors you would need `tcolorbox` per Hafid's solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can customize it by your own)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\newtcbox{\xmybox}[1][red]{on line, arc=3pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black, before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=1pt, boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}

\xmybox[green]{$F_{\text{max}}  =    1,2 $}
\xmybox[green]{ba}\xmybox[green]{na}\xmybox[green]{na}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need all of the packages that you've loaded...?

Comment: Emmm, not all, it's just example